# Add Values to existing NSDictionary From a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to work on the key pair: value of an `NSDictionary`. I need to be able to add other **key: value** to this `NSDictionary` from another method. In Swift there is `dictionary.forEach ({values [$ 0] = $ 1})` but I do not know how to do it for objective C. Can you give me an example of how to insert other values from another method into an existing `NSDictionary`?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                             kMessageFromID : currentUserID,
                             kMessageToID : recipientID,
                             kMessageTimeStamp : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSDate.new.timeIntervalSince1970],

                             };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableDictionary` has a method to merge key value pairs from another dictionary.

`- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType> *)otherDictionary;`

You can also do fast enumeration on an `NSDictionary` which is comparable to `forEach` method of `Swift.Dictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = ...;

for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    id value = dictionary[key];
    mutableDict[key] = value;
}
```